# Best way to inject a class whose instantiation cannot be controlled?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, code-migration

I'm fairly new to Guice so hopefully this isn't an obvious question...

I'm dealing with a framework which dynamically instantiates one of my application classes  (let's call it `C`) using reflection, so I have no control over its instantiation.  Furthermore, there is no easy way for me to access a newly created `C` after the framework has instantitated it.  HEre's what `C` would look like:

```
    public class C implements I {

        public C() {
            // this ctor is invoked by the framework so can't use DI here?
        }        

        public void initialize() {
            // this is a post instantiation hook which the f/w will invoke
        }

        private void m() {
            Dependency d = Dependency.getInstance();
            d.doSmth();
        }
    }
```

I would like `C` to acquire `Dependency` using DI.  Here `Dependency` is clearly a singleton but this needn't be the case generally.

I have come up with two possible solutions, neither of which feels very tidy, so I thought I'd ask the experts:

1. Static injection.  I struggle to see how this improves drastically over the service locator anti-pattern though - I end up with non final static fields which could be manipulated externally... hmmm.
2. The framework supports a hook for `C` to initialize itself post instantiation (the `initialize()` method shown above).  This method could self-inject the newly created instance using setter injection.

With 2, I guess this means more external alterability but at least exposes the dependency a little more explicitly for things like unit tests.  Trouble is: how do I get my hands on the Guice Injector in that case (short of relying on yet another service locator)?  I've also read (and tend to agree with) that explicitly referring to the Injector throughout app code is dubious practice.

Your insight would be really appreciated.

Many thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try statically injecting providers into C. Static injection more awkward to test. But the providers make it possible for Guice to validate your dependencies eagerly, while creating them lazily.

```
public class C implements I {
  @Inject static Provider<Dep1> dep1Provider;
  @Inject static Provider<Dep2> dep2Provider;

  ...

  public void initialize() {
    Dep1 dep1 = dep1Provider.get();
    Dep2 dep2 = dep2Provider.get();
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, this sounds similar to my option 1 above; although I suppose the usage of `Provider`s does indeed make the pattern more generically usable.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your Guice injector available by static variable and static accessor methods you can solve it like this:

```
public class C implements I {

    public C() {
        // this ctor is invoked by the framework, you can't do injection here.
    }        

    public void initialize() {
        MyGuice.getInjector().inject(this);
    }

    @Inject
    protected void init(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2) {
        this.dep1 = dep1;
        this.dep2 = dep2;
    }

    private void m() {
        dept1.doSmth();
    }
}
```

The static call is a bit of an anti-pattern, you could remove that dependency with a simple annotation that takes care of the post constructor injection if you are willing to use a solution that does code weaving or a post compile step. This way you can inject all objects even if they don't have an initialize method. You can find an example of this here: [How to inject model object with AspectJ](http://kdeveloper.com/configurable-annotation-for-guice/).

```
@Configurable
public class C implements I {

    public C() {
        // this ctor is invoked by the framework, you can't do injection here.
    }        

    @Inject
    protected void init(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2) {
        this.dep1 = dep1;
        this.dep2 = dep2;
    }

    private void m() {
        dept1.doSmth();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kdeveloper, this is more like option 2 listed in the original question and provides a useful demonstration of advanced techniques that can be used to mitigate the need for global state (ie: the Injector in your first example). My gut feel is that the remedy (DI) is starting to feel slightly worse than the illness (the service locator "anti-pattern") - in terms of maintainability of the code - but nevertheless interesting in as much as testability of the resulting code is improved compared to the static injection solution.